# Pimcore Adding Button To Panel in Object Editor

Tags: pimcore

I want to add a button in a panel in my own object editor. I was successful in adding an icon and handler in Object Editor like in the example documentation.
But i want to add a button somewhere in the panel below the editor.How do i find out which js file to extend so that i can create a menu button.

https://talk.pimcore.org/uploads/default/optimized/2X/7/725a347773479a7136600daeee66d7883ed19ae7_2_487x500.png

I have tried to extend the object class and i want to know which function gets executed to add my button to this toolbar

```
`pimcore.plugin.celumImage = Class.create(pimcore.plugin.admin, {
 postOpenObject: function (object, type) {
        console.log("dsdsd"+object.data.general.o_className);
            object.toolbar.add({
                text: t('show-pdf'),
                iconCls: 'pimcore_icon_pdf',
                scale: 'small',
                handler: function (obj) {
                    //do some stuff here, e.g. open a new window with an PDF download
                }.bind(this, object)
            });
            pimcore.layout.refresh();
    },
});`
```

Can you get the tabpanel here or should i want to extend the object class so that i can add the button in the image

Answer (score 1):

As you did not post the full class definition I can only estimate how the javascript shoud look like. You may go with the following if you just have one simple tabpabel:

```js
postOpenObject: function (object, type) {
    object.tabPanel
        .getComponent(0) // get object tab
        .getComponent(1) // get edit tabpanel
        .getComponent(0) // get class tab
        .getComponent(3) // get fourth tab in class tabpanel
        .query("*[componentCls~=object_field]")[0] // get first panel with class "object_field" - could be replaced with down(...)
        .getDockedComponent(0) // get toolbar
        .add({
            text: t('show-pdf'),
            iconCls: 'pimcore_icon_pdf',
            scale: 'small',
            handler: function (obj) {
                //do some stuff here, e.g. open a new window with an PDF download
            }.bind(this, object)
        });
})
```

Dependent on how complex the layout of your data object is (or will be) you may remove the `getComponent()` calls and just go with the `down()` call for the objects tag.

Make sure to adjust the code if you change the layout of the class and also consider adapting the code above if you are using [custom layouts](https://pimcore.com/docs/5.x/Development_Documentation/Objects/Object_Classes/Class_Settings/Custom_Layouts.html) for each layout if necessary.

You may have a look at the [Ext.js documentation for the Panel component](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/modern/Ext.Panel.html) as well, just search for the called methods.